# What are my options for classifying multiple multivariate time series and making live predictions?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, time-series

I'm looking for some ideas on how to handle a multivariate time series classification problem.

Specifically, I'm dealing with many hundreds of time series of varying length (but within the same ballpark, let's say 30% difference between the longest and shortest) with the same features and which should behave similarly. At the end of each time series is a binary outcome. Each time series is around 5000 observations of 32 features.

My challenge is that I want to be able to pass live data through a model (say halfway through the time series) and classify how likely the positive outcome is. Most material I've seen relates to forecasting a single time series, not learning characteristics from many historical individual time series to classify a new one midway through.

Right now my approach is to handle each observation as independent with some manual feature engineering and use grouped cross validation to avoid horribly overfitting on the fact that I'm training on multiple instances of the same time series (and thus the same outcome).

I'm using an LGBM which gives acceptable and even good results, but I'm sure this can't be the best approach and while the results work there's a lot of variance in the prediction across the time series. Ideally we'd have more uncertainty at the start and then a clearer picture starts to form, but right now there's a lot of jumping around in the probability score.

I'm not very familiar with time series modeling - I imagine deep learning could be a good approach with an LSTM or something like that but I'm not very experienced with DL either. I'm also looking into sktime to see if there's anything that would work for me out of the box.

Any suggestions on reading material or approaches I could use? Any help is appreciated!

**Edit**: here is an example of what the data looks like - the full dataset consists of many hundreds or thousands of time series like this one, and the feature set shown here is not the full feature set.
[image: Image showing a multivariate time series in table format]

Comment: Please share your example data format

Comment: Done @EnesKuz, does that work?

Comment: Probably you can use „half of“ the data in an LSTM with binary outcome to try to predict what would happen at the end of the sequence? Maybe you can simply add a sigmoid activation in the output layer with loss='binary_crossentropy'. Never tried it https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_weather_forecasting/

Comment: Issue could be unequal sequence length. I guess this can somehow be mitigated using „padding“ or so.